# Jenkins - Rake plugin can not find Rake

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jenkins, rake, jenkins-plugins

I'm using several Rake steps in my Jenkins job (through Rake plugin), but it claims to be unable to find Rake:

```
+ bundle update
.................................
Using rake (0.9.2.2) 
.................................
[workspace] $ rake db:drop
FATAL: rake execution failed
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "rake" (in directory "/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/myproject/workspace"): java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:475)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:244)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:216)
    at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:709)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:338)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.join(Launcher.java:345)
    at hudson.plugins.rake.Rake.perform(Rake.java:141)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:19)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:717)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:199)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:160)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:499)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1502)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:236)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:164)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:81)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:468)
    ... 15 more
Build step 'Invoke Rake' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

And if I manually specify the Ruby path in Jenkins's config:

```
[workspace] $ rake db:drop
[31mERROR: Gem rake is not installed, run `gem install rake` first.(B[m
Build step 'Invoke Rake' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

If I execute rake in Jenkins as a plain shell command, without Rake plugin:

```
+ rake db:drop
/var/lib/jenkins/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/yaml.rb:56:in `<top (required)>':
It seems your ruby installation is missing psych (for YAML output).
To eliminate this warning, please install libyaml and reinstall your ruby.
```

When I execute "bundle exec rake db:drop" happens the same but twice.

Temporarily including two lines in the job:

```
rvm pkg install libyaml
rvm reinstall 1.9.3
```

does not help. (Update: this is only warning and does not affect anything, but is quite annoying).

I have another RVM + Ruby bundle installed outside of Jenkins in ~/.rvm directory, and it works just fine.

Comment: What if you do: `bundle exec rake db:drop`

Comment: Did you ever find an sln to this?

Comment: No. Currently I have abandoned Jenkins as an inconvenient thing, so my research in this area has stopped.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it helps you but I had a similar issue. Problem was the Ruby path where I installed the Rake gem wasn't in the path for the Jenkins process.

The init.d script I was using (/etc/init.d/jenkins) had hardcoded the PATH variable:

```
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin
```

Since I'm using ChefDK I added the embedded ChefDK Ruby to the init.d scripts path:

```
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/opt/chefdk/embedded/bin:/opt/chefdk/bin/
```

You probably need to modify path based on where your Ruby is installed. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: I had to do exactly this two days ago. +1

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Rake Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Rake+Plugin).

For our needs the [RVM Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/RVM+Plugin) did the job, the rest like bundle did we put in a script/shell build-step.

Comment: These errors appear namely when I use this Rake plugin. When I try without it, everything is fine. Also I'm using RVM plugin too.